# Argument not passing to array_search correctly

Tags: php, arrays, search, command-line

Hi I have a problem whereby I am running a command using terminal which passes the value "a" to a file called "category".

Then I run my php file and I wish to then set the contents of "category" to a variable called `$datatype`. This is successful because when I echo the variable I get "a" to print. However I want to then lookup this value in an array and return the corresponding value "1". It doesn't work unless I actually set `$datatype` directly by calling`$dataype = "2";` Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
<?
//PUT VALUE "a" INTO A FILE CALLED category
echo shell_exec("cat ".$filename." | cut -f2 | head -1 > category");

$datatype = file_get_contents("category");
echo file_get_contents("category"); // PRINTS "a"
echo $datatype; //PRINTS "a"

$array = array(
          "1"=>"a",
          "2"=>"b",
          "3"=>"c",
          "4"=>"d",
          );

$key = array_search($datatype, $array);
echo $key; // DOESN'T PRINT ANYTHING!!!! I EXPECT "1" TO BE PRINTED



//IF I CHANGE TO BELOW IT WORKS...."1" IS PRINTED
$datatype = "a";

?>
```

Using what Xorifelse suggested:

```
 file_get_contents("category", NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
```

Or what yardpenalty suggested:

```
 array_search($datatype[0], $array)
```

These both work. However my actual problem invloves words of varying length and not just single chars. This tells me it must be a problem with the space after the word? I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Try `echo "'$datatype'";` and look for hidden chars, like `new line`, etc because `"a" != "a\n"`

Comment: Did u try file_get_contents("category", NULL, NULL, 0, 1); so it returns the first character as a string only?

Comment: Or match the first char in string `$datatype` by doing `array_search($datatype[0], $array)`

Comment: Thanks so much both, really good suggestions, but please see my question, I have updated it with the problem I still face. Thanks

Comment: I think I might have found it, when I echo strlen($datatype); I get 19 for a particular example when the actual length I expect is 18. Is there a quick way to clip the last character or when its saved to escape it?

Comment: Whichever of you would like to answer the question I can close it because you have correctly answered the question I have asked. :)

Comment: For anyone interested the problem I still have is located here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322842/cat-filename-cut-f2-head-1-newfile-contains-more-characters-than-expecte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to allow varying lengths for your parameter you can use the `trim() function`. Just make sure you have a switch case that handles all of the possible string lengths like so:

```
function handleDataType($datatype){

 $temp = trim($datatype);
 $key = "";
 switch ($temp) {
       case strlen($temp) == 1:
       case strlen($temp) == 2:
       case strlen($temp) == 4:
           $key = array_search($temp, $array);
           break;
       default:
           throw new Exception('Parameter is out of bounds!');
    } 
    $array = array(
          "1"=>"a",
          "2"=>"to",
          "3"=>"four",
          "4"=>"d",
          );

$key = array_search($datatype, $array);

   return $key;
}


try {

    $datatype = file_get_contents("category");
    echo handleDataType("six") . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```